# Extracting mail addresses

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file that contains lines like this:

`user=<xxxxxxx@asd.com.tr>,

user=<yyyyyyy@asd.com.tr>,

user=<zzzzzzz@asd.com.tr>,

user=<ccccccc@asd.com.tr>,

user=<bbbbbbb@asd.com.tr>,

user=<aaaaaaa@asd.com.tr>,`

What is the best way to extract mail addresses from this file?

Comment: `egrep -o '[^<]+@[^>]+'`, maybe?

Comment: Can you explain this a little?

Comment: See `man grep`. It will find any string which contains an `@` preceded by any characters different than `<` and followed by any characters different than `>`. - Should work fine, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `awk` as given in the other answer.

You could use `sed` or `perl` or `ruby` similar: e.g.

```
perl -wlne '/<(.*)>/ and print $1' file
```

But using `bash` as requested, it is possible, too.

First step. Just outputting the file line by line:

```
while read line; do echo $line; done <file
```

Next step removing the unwanted prefix and suffix:

```
while read line; do line=${line##user=<}; line=${line%%>,}; echo $line; done <file
```

The same a bit more generic and shortened:

```
while read line; do line=${line##*<}; echo ${line%%>*}; done <file
```

This works for your example and should also work with other shells.

If you just want to chop a couple of characters in front and at the end you can use:

```
while read line; do echo ${line:6:-2}; done <file
```

You can read the fine man page of bash (`man bash`) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there could be a better way than this, but off the top of my head
`awk -F '<|>' '{ print $2 }' filename`

Answer (score 0):

If insist using bash, in newer version:

Shell Parameter Expansion: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html
String Length: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#string_length
Substring expansion: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_expansion

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    len=$((${#line}-8))
    echo ${line:6:$len}
done < file
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `${line:6:-2}`?

Comment: For compatibility reasons. Negative Length may not work in previous version of Bash. e.g. my RHEL 6 pre-installed Bash 4.1. Error occurs: `-2: substring expression < 0`

Comment: Note that `${PARAMETER:OFFSET:-LENGTH}` is available on Bash 4.2-alpha or later.